# Indexing a list of strings in for loop

Tags: python

For this code:

```
s = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
for v in s:
   print(v[1])
```

Why does printing this index result in this output?

```
p
a
h
```

**I know that it is outputting the 2nd position within each string**, but I was expecting it to output banana since it was the in the 2nd position in the list. Is there a way to get the output to be banana?

Comment: Try just `print(s[1])`, without a loop.

Comment: v takes on the value of each item in the list.  So on the first iteration, v is "apple", and the second character of apple is "p".

Comment: "I know that it is outputting the 2nd position within each string" Well, yes, because that's what the code asks for: "**`for` each** `v` that is `in s`, `print(v[1])`". "Is there a way to get the output to be banana?" Well, how many times do you want to print? *Just once*, right? So, *no loop*. What is the thing from which you want the second element? `s`, right? How do you get the element you want? `[1]`, right? What do you want to do with it? `print`, right? So, put those pieces together.

Comment: Your history of previous questions suggests a level of familiarity with Python where you should be able to figure this out yourself. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to solve problems yourself first before asking here. Also keep in mind that sometimes it's best to just take a break. (Voting to close as a typo.)

Comment: You're right. Thank you for that. @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 1):

As Bill says, the for loop prints the second character of each string within your list s. I think you may be misunderstanding how the for loop works.

`for v in s` iterates over the elements of s, setting v=apple, then v=banana, and finally v=cherry. When v=apple, you are printing v[1] which is the second character of apple as strings are iterable in python - this is "p". When v=banana, again you are printing the second character of v which is now "a".

To get the second element of any list, you simply do list[1] - which is just `print(s[1])` in this case.